# Matching slug terms from one array to those in array of WP_Term objects to output term names

Tags: array, slug, terms

I'm using WordPress's `get_terms` to return an array of `WP_Term` objects containing the term_id, name, slug, etc. for the child terms of a given taxonomy. I've saved this array to `$tax_terms`. I have a different array—`$active_filters`—containing just the *slugs* of terms that match certain taxonomy terms; for instance, from a `var_dump` of `$active_filters`:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => string 'term-1' (length=6)
  1 => string 'term-2' (length=6)
  2 => string 'term-3' (length=6)
```

I'm wondering if there's a way I can run a `foreach` that will compare this array of term slugs to those in the array returned by `get_terms` and return the `name` for any matched slug? So, the example above would output "Term 1", "Term 2", "Term 3". I've tried using `array_search` but to no avail, thus far. Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) ?

This will give you an array of term names which matched your slugs in $active_filters:

```
$matched_terms = array_map(function($term) use ($active_filters){
    if(in_array($term->slug, $active_filters)){
        return $term->name;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }

}, $tax_terms);


//remove the empty array elements which came from terms which didn't match a slug
$matched_terms = array_filter($matched_terms);
```